# Possible for 2 transactions from the same address within the same block?

Tags: utxo

I am not talking about double spend. I am referring to 2 diff txns

For example, Alice has 10 btc. She sends 3 btc to Bob and 4 to Tom. Is that possible in the same block if she has 2 UTXOs with each UTXO >= 4 BTC? UT

What if she only has 1 UTXO of 10 BTC? will it be possible to include both txns in the same block?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Prayank's answer, ...

Alice can pay both Bob and Tom in a single transaction with three outputs (Bob, Tom, change) and using either your two input UTXOs example or just your one input UTXO example.

The inputs just have to sum to more than the sum of the outputs. So inputs of 3+4 or 10 or 1+3+10000 all work. The amount of change returned to Alice varies.

Alice can also construct, starting with only one UTXO, two transactions that can be put into the same block. This is because a transaction can use as an input a UTXO created by an earlier transaction in the same block.

Answer (score 1):

> For example, Alice has 10 btc. She sends 3 btc to Bob and 4 to Tom. Is that possible in the same block if she has 2 UTXOs with each UTXO >= 4 BTC?

Yes it's possible to spend 2 UTXO and get both transactions included in same block.

> What if she only has 1 UTXO of 10 BTC? will it be possible to include both txns in the same block?

1 UTXO can only be spent in a transaction except if you are replacing earlier transaction using RBF. So there won't be 2 transactions.